# Understanding foldLeft function - how are parameter values typed?

Tags: scala

Reading the signature of foldLeft :   `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {`
z Type does not seem to be utilized in below implementation ?

f corresponds to `(List[Int](), 0)` in foldLeft signature ?

```
object foldleftfun {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  val numbers = List(1, 2, 3)                     //> numbers  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

  numbers.foldLeft((List[Int](), 0)) {
    (resultingTuple, currentInteger) => {

            println(resultingTuple)
            println(currentInteger)
            println("")

        (currentInteger :: resultingTuple._1, currentInteger + resultingTuple._2)
      }
  }                                               //> (List(),0)
                                                  //| 1
                                                  //| 
                                                  //| (List(1),1)
                                                  //| 2
                                                  //| 
                                                  //| (List(2, 1),3)
                                                  //| 3
                                                  //| 
                                                  //| res0: (List[Int], Int) = (List(3, 2, 1),6)

}
```

Comment: In your case, `z` is `(List[Int](), 0)`. It is the starting value. You defined `f` in the curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the API makes this a little unclear. the way I usually look at it is this:

foldLeft(accumulator)((accumulator,elem) => someOperation)

the first accumulator is just whatever start value you want. The return type of this foldLeft will be the type of whatever value you give for accumulator.  foldLeft iterates over the elements of the List you call it on so that each element of that List becomes the value of elem in the foldLeft. accumulator in the second set of parentheses gets updated after each iteration.

For example:

val ls = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)

ls.foldLeft(0)((acc,elem) => acc + elem)

would return 21, which you could then capture in some variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

z is the "zero value" for type B.

An example that might make this a bit clearer. I want to count the number of items in a List of String which start with the string "cat"

```
type A = String
type B = Int
val m: List[A] = List("cat", "catatonic", "dog", "catamaran")
val z: B = 0
val f: (B, A) => B = {(count, word) =>
  if(word.startsWith("cat"))
    count + 1
  else
    count
}

m.foldLeft(z)(f)
```

In this example, the first word needs to have a corresponding count, without the z value of 0 we wouldn't necessarily know where to start.

Note: Obviously no one is going to break out all the pieces like this for "real" code, it's done to show how all the pieces and types fit in the example.